# How to download a joined image as a CSV file on my local computer?

Tags: google-earth-engine, csv, google-earth-engine-python-api, download

I used a Landsat tile to extract information (images) from different satellites. Then, I add each image to a band like below. So, How can I download it (`img_joined`) as a CSV file to my local computer?

```
img_joined = img_initial.addBands(img_2).addBands(img_3).addBands(img_4).addBands(img_5)
```

I have tried below, and it showed the request size was too big. Note, I need to download the data with 30-m scale.

```
geemap.ee_export_image(img_joined, filename=filename, scale=30, region=region, file_per_band=False)
```

Any ideas, comments, and suggestions are very appreciated!

P.S. If I download the joined images with 300-m pixel resolution and download each band (like the code below), that works. If download the joined images as one image with different bands, it doesn't work.

```
geemap.ee_export_image(img_joined, filename='IMG_Test', scale=300, region=region, file_per_band=True)
```

Comment: if `img_joined` is an image (ee.Image), how are you planning to download it as a Comma-Separated Values (CSV) file?? I've never used that function, but I suppose it exports the image as a TIFF file

Comment: The `img_joined` is an image (ee.Image) containing several bands (e.g., 13 bands). Now, I know that extract image values to the points is a way to get the CSV file. But, there is a limitation, we cannot download too much data. For example, 5,000*5,000 points with 13 bands.

Comment: `geemap.ee_export_image()` is just one example of image downloading. This function works on the GEE Python API platform and only works for separated images. Anyway, it's just examples. My final goal is download the image with different bands as CSV file.